# How to add a reference to another method in documentation Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, documentation, xcode8.2

I am adding documentation to one of my methods in xCode 8.2.1. I want to add a reference to another method of my project, so that when the user clicks on it, xCode moves to this method. It could be possible?

[image: Add link to anotherMethod]

[I want to make "anotherMethod" clickable]